# AFNetworkReachabilityManager status is unknown

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I started using `AFNetworking`'s reachability manager instead of Apple's `Reachability` class but it doesn't work. Its reachability status is `AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown` despite the internet connection is turned on on the device. This is my code:

```
     reachabilityManager = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager];
    [reachabilityManager startMonitoring];

    [reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status){
         NSLog(@"Current status %@", reachabilityManager.localizedNetworkReachabilityStatusString);
    }];
```

I put `NSLog` inside the block but i don't mean to say that i see results there. Actually the block is never called (while my device has normal internet connection). I just check the status before performing my first network request and i see it is `-1` i.e. unknown. What's wrong?

This is how i check reachability status:

```
- (BOOL)connected
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
     return YES;
#else
     NSLog(@"Status %d", reachabilityManager.networkReachabilityStatus);
     return reachabilityManager.reachable;
#endif
}
```

Comment: show how you check for reachability status, please… as to `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock` not being called: it is called only when a change in reachability occurs -- try switching off your router, e.g. and see what happens in the app...

Comment: @sergio I've updated my question. this is the example of how I do that

Comment: the only thing I can suggest is debugging into `reachable` or `networkReachabilityStatus` and see why it is returning the odd value...

Comment: WAG: What happens if you move `startMonitoring` after setting the change block? And as @segio pointed out what happens if you, for example, turn off your connection while the monitoring is active? Does the block get called then?